# How to pass a variable from a directive (ngModel) into the html outside of the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got a custom directive with an html template and it basically is a menu option. When a user makes a selection it updates the ng-model variable within the directive.

But I would like for the ng-model variable within the directive passed outside of the directive into the html page.

Here's the code snippets:

Directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')

        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.sortByOptions = [
                { value:'red', displayText:'Redder' },
                { value:'blue', displayText:'Bluer' },
                { value:'gold', displayText:'Golder' },
                { value:'brown', displayText:'Browner' }
            ];
        }]

    )

        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

    myDirective.$inject = [];
    function myDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'mydirective/sorting.html',

        }
    }
})();
```

HTML Template for the directive:

```
<select ng-model="sortBy" ng-options="sortByOption.displayText for sortByOption in sortByOptions track by sortByOption.value"> </select> {{sortBy.value}}
```

HTML of the Page:

```
        <div class="col-md-8 form-inline" my-directive>
        </div>

<!-- need ng-model variable from my-directive passed into sortBy --> <!-- it's being called on same page. I turned a menu options into a directive to save from copying/pasting same code everywhere. when the menu option gets selected it populates a list which is the li you see below -->

    <li ng-repeat="object in objects | filter: searchTool | orderBy: (sortAscending ? '' : '-') + sortBy">
        <div class="plank">
            <div class="plank-header">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass ng-model="sortBy" value from the directive which is chosen by the user into other parts of the page called sortBy that is within the li.

It would be awesome if someone can give an example of what they did.

Comment: Where do you use `myDirective`?

Comment: Seems like you have a 2-way going on there so it should work unless you are running into `dot` problem.. ng-repeat creates a child scope, fyi... So it all depends on where you are using `myDirective`

Comment: i call myDirective in the HTML of the Page

Comment: Directives have access to the parent scope by default however you have seem to have an isolate scope, which means the value of sortBy is only accessible within the directive.

Comment: @Donal that is why OP has  `sortBy: "="`

Comment: which is my question... how do i not make the scope isolated so i can call the ng-model in other places...

Comment: by adding a scope property, you have made it an isolate scope - so just remove the scope property and use it in the controller.

Comment: @adbarads try one thing. In your controller set `$scope.options= {};` and set `orderBy: (sortAscending ? '' : '-') + options.sortBy"` in your filter then when doing 2way on mydirective bind it via `sort="options.sortBy"`. And btw how do you get access to `sortByOptions`, defined in the parent controller, inside the directive?

Comment: @adbarads where are you using the directive in your html?

Comment: @PSL = is for 2-way binding.

Comment: @Donal yes i was clarifying your question.. `which means the value of sortBy is only accessible within the directive` there is a 2 way binding which means consumer can get the updates (provided it has been used properly and there is no dot notation issue where it is trying to get accessed). But unfortunately we have no liberty to see that piece of code i guess.. :(

Comment: So, if you set `scope:true`, this will create a child scope that will prototypically inherit from its parent, so you will be able to access values defined on parent's scope in your directive.

Comment: @PSL - what part of the code are you looking for? I tried what you asked it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @adbarads :) not just me.. if you read all the comments everyone has been asking where are you using the directive, where means "please show us". How is it related to this piece if html that you have shown..

Comment: done, I was just calling the directive above the same html page in that manner.

Comment: but it sounds like it may be related to the ng-repeat someone was talking about? that it created a child scope?

Comment: Yes it could be.. i only commented it before.. checkout my prev comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:
1) added a scope.$watch to allow my directive to listen for a change in that variable on the DOM. Then it will set the new value in the controller

2) Added the controller into the directive. I originally forgot to add a line in the function colorSorter to return the controller

3) I did not need to modify the directive's html template or the main html template for the page to get it working.

Here is the directive:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('myModule')

        .controller('sortController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.sortByOptions = [
                { value:'red', text:'Redder' },
                { value:'blue', text:'Bluer' },
                ];
            $scope.sortBy = {value: undefined}
        }]
    )
        .directive('colorSorter', colorSorter);
    colorSorter.$inject = [];

    function colorSorter() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'app/color-sorter/color-sorter.html',
            controller: 'sortByController',
            link: function (scope) {

                scope.$watch('sortBy.value', function (value) {
                console.log(value);
                })
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar by essentially exposing the variable in your directive to your controller. You can do this by passing a function from your controller into your directive such that that function gets called and essentially sets a variable in your controller.  Something like this.

```
   <div mydirective call-outside-function="setSortBy".....>

   mycontroller function(...) {

      $scope.setSortBy = function(sb) {
        $scope.localSortBy = sb;
      };
   }

   mydirective .....
      link: function(scope,element,attrs) {

          scope.$watch('sortBy',function(newval) {
                 attrs.callOutsideFunction(newval); 
          });
      }
```

Probably not the most elegant solution but it works

Comment: if I expose the variable to my controller that would make any page be able to access that variable?

Comment: No, it would make it so only pages inside that controller could access it. But unless you have multiple controllers on the page such that the directive is in one controller and the controller you are accessing it from is a different controller, this won't be an issue.  If that is the case you should probably create a service that holds the variable and the directive and your other controller share the service and thus have access to the value.

Comment: if you don't mind elaborating on your answer. I tried to implement what you suggested and I couldn't get it to work. My java script skills are very new. Can you show an example?